# Twisted irc python bot - buffering messages

Tags: python, twisted, irc, bots

> "Why does it take a long time for data I send with transport.write to arrive at the other side of the connection?"
>
> Twisted can only send data after you give up control of execution to the reactor. For example, if you have an infinite loop writing data to a transport, the data will never actually be sent since control will never leave your code and return to the reactor."

I found this in the twisted FAQ, it is exactly as my problem. Is there a way to fix this so I can send messages instantly and not wait for the loop to finish?

Comment: There really isn't a easy way to flush outgoing Twisted buffers, you should just keep execution light.

Comment: But I need it for my bot. I need to write 10 lines (1 line per 2 sec) with a command. It isn't possible to do this since twisted just writes all of the lines in a second and it gets excess flood.

Comment: Just write 5 lines at once with `\n`

Comment: What do you mean 5 lines at once with \n?

Comment: imagine your lines are in a list
`'\n'.join(lines[0:5])`

Comment: are you calling reactor.run()?

Comment: I actually fixed it, it seems there is a lineRate which you can set. It works. :) thanks anyway everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  You cannot send messages instantly.  Control must return to the event loop.  Fortunately, the problem you're really trying to solve (inferred from comments on the question), rate limiting the messages you send, doesn't require being able to do this.  Instead, stop using `time.sleep` in a loop and start using `reactor.callLater` to delay the execution of code.  Or use features of the IRC API which do these things for you (which you seem to have discovered already, `lineRate`).